# Cannot find 'Folder referenced' file in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I cannot seem to reference a file that is packaged with my app on my development iPhone 6.  It can be found fine in XCode's simulator of iPhone 6.

The file I am trying to reference:

[image]

Where I reference the file:

```
NSString *epubPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"epubjs/ios.html"];
```

The error this returns:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “ios.html” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/containers/Bundle/Application/8BB11DEC-4823-4603-83E7-F4C23BC3C983/BSAVA.app/epubjs/ios.html, NSUnderlyingError=0x126df1110 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

I have tried various things to get a list of files in the NSBundle and/or search for the file but I cannot get to it within the app when it's running on the actual device:

```
//
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.html'"];
NSArray *onlyHTMLs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
NSLog(@".html file array: %@", onlyHTMLs);
//
NSError * error;
NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resourcePath error:&error];
//
NSString * documentsPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BSAVA"];
NSArray * directoryContents2 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:&error];
//
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ios" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ios" withExtension:@"html"];
//
```

These all return nil.

Comment: Show in finder option may help you to check the correct path of that folder.

Comment: is the file target set? this is in the right hand panel of XCode when the file is selected. You are looking for "Target Membership"

Comment: I can find the file ok on the development Mac using finder.  My app cannot find the bundled version of the file when it is running.

Comment: The file is probably not being bundled with the app.  Confirm that first.

Comment: That's kind of what I am asking - how to confirm it?  (It works in simulator as mentioed before but this might be referencing local copy and not bundled copy?)

Comment: @Dominic Target membership has a tick by my app's name

Comment: Find the build directory (in `DerivedData`) and look at it in the shell.  Look at the build log to see where that is.

Comment: @Droppy I have looked at the build log and can see other files have been included but that folder (epubjs) and its files don't appear to have been.  Any ideas as to why? or what I need to do to get them included?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/CreatingaCopyFilesBuildPhase.html

Comment: @Droppy ok this makes sense, put this as an answer and I'll accept it explaining how it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, from conversation with you in the comments, that you have simply forgotten to bundle the files with the app and hence they don't exist at runtime at all.  I do not understand the difference in behaviour between the Simulator and the Device, but I expect that was a red herring as it should fail on both.

This [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/CreatingaCopyFilesBuildPhase.html) shows how to copy files into the app bundle during a build.

Comment: In previous apps I simply made the app download the files it needed after installation (for various reasons).  For this app I bundled these files but as Droppy mentioned I had forgotten to set the build phase to actually include the files.  Doing this resolved the issue and my app can now find the files again.